# When using a docker volume, are files up to date when the container is restarted?

Tags: docker

I have multiple docker containers running on a host machine that point to a directory (volume) as part of a `docker run` command. If I update these files and restart all of the containers, will the containers pick up the new files? Or do I need to completely stop and remove the containers for the file changes to take effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you volume is [host directory mounted as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) (`docker run -v <host>/path:<container>/path`), then you don't need to stop/restart anything: any file update would be visible from within the running container.

If it is a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockervolumes/#adding-a-data-volume), its changes are persisted when the container is deleted/recreated.

If it is a data volume container, any file change is immediately visible from any containers that have mounted that data volume container.